# inconsistent result when getting location from ip address

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a location from an ip address, the code for that is:

```
import urllib.request
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://geolocation-db.com/json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```

This does produce a result but it is the wrong result and gives me the wrong address (although the right countr. However, when I use a website like https://iplocation.com/ I do get my proper address.

I am quite confused why there are different results, could someone help?

Comment: Different service offers different results. You can try other web service such as ip2location.io and compare which one is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I realised that the website itself is producing weird and inaccurate results. Didn't even think that could be the case.